# examine several datum to check if there exist a regulations or not in R

Tags: r

I have 11 datum.

Data 1 is made up of several sets of sequence. And each sequence in data 1 is made up of 2 numbers.
It looks like:

```
[1] 1 2
[1] 1 3
[1] 1 4
```

Data 2 is made up of several sets of sequence. And each sequence in data 2 is made up of 3 numbers.
It looks like:

```
[1]  1 2 3
[1]  1 2 4
[1]  1 3 4
[1]  1 2 5
```

Data 3 is made up of several sets of sequence. And each sequence in data 3 is made up of 4 numbers.
It looks like:

```
[1]  1 2 3 5
[1]  1 3 4 5
[1]  1 2 3 4
[1]  1 2 4 5
```

Data 4 is made up of several sets of sequence. And each sequence in data 4 is made up of 5 numbers.
.........
.........
Data 11 is made up of several sets of sequence. And each sequence in data 11 is made up of 12 numbers.

Take any sequence from data 1 then add a number to this sequence to become a new sequence (sequence 2).
And this new sequence (sequence 2) exactly exists in data 2. Then add another number to the sequence 2 to get a new sequence (sequence 3).
And this new sequence (sequence 3) exactly exists in data 3..........
...........
The final step is to take any sequence from data 10 then add a number to this sequence to become a new sequence (sequence 11).And this new sequence (sequence 11) exactly exists in data 11.

ex:
data 5 　→　[1] 4 5 8 9 14 15　add "10"　→　　get  [1]  4 5 8 9 10 14 15 (exist in data 6)
data 6 　→　[1] 4 5 8 9 10 14 15  add "11"　→　　get  [1] 4 5 8 9 10 11 14 15  (exist in data 7)

And I alweady have data matrix from data 1 to data 11. Data 1 has 48 sequences. Data 2 has 48 sequences. Data 3 has 147 sequences. Data 4 has 73 sequences. Data 5 has 12 sequences... Data 11 has 1 sequences

I wander if there is code can help me to fine out the regulation between the 11 datum.

Comment: How is this data stored in R? Are the sequences always increasing? If so, are all increasing sequences of the relevant length included? What do you mean by "regulation between" the data?

Comment: I got those data from previously compute result. I have no idea about how to store these different data in R so that I could use 11 datum together to analyze. I want to find a certain sequence. This certain sequence has a basic principle. Add one number in each step to get a new sequence. And this new sequence exactly exists in another data.